# What Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern matches "all"?

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

In addition to `/etc/apt/sources.list` I have a couple of origins defined in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` How can I adjust `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` so that all origins are allowed?

I tried setting an empty string as follows:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
  "";
}
```

but this results in an error message:

```
$ sudo unattended-upgrades -d
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Initial whitelisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['']
empty match string matches nothing
empty match string matches nothing
empty match string matches nothing
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [README](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md):

> If you already configure what to install via apt pinning, you can simply use "origin=*", e.g.:
>
> ```
> Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
>     "origin=*";
> };
> ```

Comment: Does this use the same sources as a manual update, i.e. does it ignore disabled sources?

Comment: @Silicomancer yes, it uses the same repositories as a manual update.